# How to pass variable from controller to model after function execution Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a function in a controller that when executed, check for existence of a record in a table and returns that record. This function is used as validation of a model inside the same controller. For example:

```
public function somethingValidate() {

    $someVariable = SomeTable::find()->where(['some_id' => $someVariable])->one();
    if ($model) {
        return $model;
    } else {
         return false;
```

Here is the validation part of controller:

```
public function actionSave() {
    $model = new TestModel() {
           if ($this->somethingValidate()) {
                try {
                  --- REST OF THE CODE ---
```

How can i now, pass `$someVariable` variable into a `TestModel` and manipulate the data either on save or beforeSave.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please correct your example first for better understanding. What is `$model` there? Where is `$someVariable` taken from?

Comment: `$model` is an actual model being saved with RESTful call, the `$someVariable` is taken from different table, different model and is used only for validation. If record exists, there is a id field referenced in `$model` table, where I need to save `$someVariable->id` Due to the nature of the project, I'm unable to provide better code example, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, an `Investment` amount should be more or equal with the `Proposal`'s `min_investment` value. Below is the `beforeValidate()` function in `Investment` model.

```
public function beforeValidate()
    {
        parent::beforeValidate();

        $proposal = Proposal::findOne($this->proposal_id);

        if ($this->amount < $proposal->min_investment)
        {
            $this->addError('amount', Yii::t('app', 'Minimum amount should be ' . $proposal->min_investment));
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That is basically it. Now, what I really need is after the validation is successful, I need to save `$proposal->id` to another model.

Comment: I still don't understand the logic of your application. If I post my `Proposal` model full code which have `afterSave()` function, could it be more useful for you? Inside the `afterSave()` function, I create another row/data to `ProposalLog` model.